# Different definitions of the cross entropy loss function

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, softmax, cross-entropy

I started off learning about neural networks with the neuralnetworksanddeeplearning dot com tutorial. In particular in the [3rd chapter](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html) there is a section about the cross entropy function, and defines the cross entropy loss as:

$C = -\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_x \sum\limits_j (y_j \ln a^L_j + (1-y_j) \ln (1 - a^L_j))$

However, reading the [Tensorflow introduction](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#training), the cross entropy loss is defined as:

$C = -\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_x \sum\limits_j (y_j \ln a^L_j)$ (when using the same symbols as above)

Then searching around to find what was going on I found another set of notes: (https://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#softmax-classifier) that uses a completely different definition of the cross entropy loss, albeit this time for an softmax classifier rather than for a neural network.

Can someone explain to me what is going on here? Why are there discrepancies btw. what people define the cross-entropy loss as? Is there just some overarching principle?

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260505/machine-learning-should-i-use-a-categorical-cross-entropy-or-binary-cross-entro/260537#260537

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These three definitions are essentially the same.

1) The [Tensorflow introduction](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#training),
$$C = -\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_x\sum\limits_{j} (y_j \ln a_j).$$

2) For binary classifications $j=2$, it becomes
$$C = -\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_x (y_1 \ln a_1 + y_2 \ln a_2)$$
and because of the constraints $\sum_ja_j=1$ and $\sum_jy_j=1$, it can be rewritten as
$$C = -\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_x (y_1 \ln a_1 + (1-y_1) \ln (1-a_1))$$
which is the same as in the [3rd chapter](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html).

3) Moreover, if $y$ is a [one-hot vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) (which is commonly the case for classification labels) with $y_k$ being the only non-zero element, then the cross entropy loss of the corresponding sample is
$$C_x=-\sum\limits_{j} (y_j \ln a_j)=-(0+0+...+y_k\ln a_k)=-\ln a_k.$$

In the [cs231 notes](https://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#softmax-classifier), the cross entropy loss of one sample is given together with softmax normalization as
$$C_x=-\ln(a_k)=-\ln\left(\frac{e^{f_k}}{\sum_je^{f_j}}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

In the [third chapter](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html), equation (63) is the cross entropy applied to multiple sigmoids (that may not sum to 1) while in the [Tensoflow intro](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers#training) the cross-entropy is computed on a softmax output layer.

As explained by [dontloo](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223799/different-definitions-of-the-cross-entropy-loss-function/224491#224491) both formula are essentially equivalent for two classes but it is not when more than two classes are considered. Softmax makes sense for multiclass with exclusive classes (*i.e* when there is only one label per sample, that allow the one-hot encoding of labels) while (multiple) sigmoids can be used to describe a multilabel problem (i.e with samples that are possibly positive for several classes).

See this other [dontloo answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/198047) as well.